# How do I make a panda series into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

My issue is I got the values of a column called urls from a dataframe and made the values equal a panda series called urlsCleaned. I then cleaned the panda series urls to my liking called urlsCleaned. The issue I have is I want to change the dataframe column called urls and make it match the URLs with the panda series urlsCleaned. The values in the urlsCleaned have roughly 149 rows still and the dataframe called NWO_data is roughly 349 rows. It is important for the values to match up because the urls are associated with usernames and likes. Should I create a new column in the panda series that keeps a number value before I start cleaning that way I can match the values up? If so how would I do that?

```
import csv
import twint
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nest_asyncio
import re
nest_asyncio.apply()

NWO_data = pd.read_csv("TwitterLinksNWO.csv")
urlsCleaned = NWO_data["urls"]
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('youtu.be', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('youtube', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('bitly', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned[~urlsCleaned.str.contains('4444')]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "make it match". Could you provide a sample of each input dataframe and a sample of your expected output, along with the code for what you've tried so far, to make a [mcve]

Comment: The person who answered solved my problem. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it to a new column:

```
NWO_data = pd.read_csv("TwitterLinksNWO.csv")
NWO_data["urlsCleaned"] = NWO_data["urls"]
NWO_data["urlsCleaned"] = NWO_data["urlsCleaned"].str.replace('youtu.be', '4444')
NWO_data["urlsCleaned"] = NWO_data["urlsCleaned"].str.replace('youtube', '4444')
NWO_data["urlsCleaned"] = NWO_data["urlsCleaned"].str.replace('bitly', '4444')
NWO_data = NWO_data[~NWO_data.urlsCleaned.str.contains("4444")]
```